# Is it possible to cross compile for Windows, from linux, when static libraries are not available?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dll, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a project using Qt, OpenCV and FlyCapture2 libraries into an executable for a Windows 8 target system. I am running ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately the FlyCapture2 SDK only provides shared libraries so I cannot compile these statically.

It is fine for me to simply include the libraries in the same directory as the executable but seeing as how i'm building the project on Linux (using Qt Creator) I am not sure how to appropriately link for a Windows target system. Here is my current .pro file:

```
CONFIG+=static

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -static -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lflycapture -lflycapture-c -lflycapturegui
## Is it possible to link to a .dll for windows here?
```

Is it possible to link to a .dll for the Windows target system? Is there a solution for this problem that I am not seeing? This is my first attempt at cross-compilation. Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= your_curreny_so_lib_path 
then 
    make

Comment: So the compiler will search for libraries in my_current_solib_path first which will run on linux and then, on Windows, it will not find this path and so find the libraries in the directory? Is that correct?

Comment: I was confused about your mean.if you can find .so ,you can add it into linux /usr/lib which linux compiler will search .so first.The other way is add your .so path to /etc/ld.config which has the same consequence with the firt way.

Comment: How does this help me run my program on Windows?

Comment: .dll file is loaded when applications called.you can compile your project to .exe ,then run it in Windows,if exe reminds can find .dll ,then you can add .dll file to C:/Windows/system32.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Something as follows:

```
LIBS += -Wl,--start-group

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -static -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lflycapture -lflycapture-c -lflycapturegui

LIBS += -Wl,--end-group
```

This may Work for you. Hope this Helps.